# Python colour on my screen question anywhere

Tags: python

I am currently using this code:

```
import ImageGrab
px = ImageGrab.grab().load()
for y in range(0, 100, 10):
    for x in range(0, 100, 10):
        color = px[x, y]
```

This checks the colour in the very middle of my screen. The only issue is, I don’t know how to check if a specific colour is anywhere on the screen. Basically, what I am trying to do is, check for a specific colour on my screen and if it’s there then move to it.
Any ideas what I can do? i tried google and stuff but nothing worked.

Comment: In your loop, you are already checking every color on the screen. All you have to do is check in your loop if 'color' is the desired color. If so, then you have your X and Y. 

I don't know what you mean by 'jumping to it'. Do you mean moving your cursor to that spot?

Comment: Also, keep in mind you aren't actually checking EVERY pixel, as you are iterating by 10 pixels in each direction

Comment: Sounds like homework, and you're expected to be able to figure this out on your own to learn about the nature of the structures you are working with and what they are capable of.  Create a new python function that takes two integers and then uses that to print the color at `px[x,y]`.  Then create another function that takes a color and iterates every pixel on the screen and if it's the one you want you return the coordinates of that one. Also this kind of question is barely allowed on stackoverflow since it doesn't provide value to others.

Comment: @Vvamp I want to check my screen, for a specific colour and if it’s for example to my right or left or anywhere my mouse will move towards it.

Comment: @Jay Does the mouse have to slowly move to that point, or can it also be instant?

Comment: I want to check every pixel to ensure if it’s the colour or not. @Vvamp

Comment: @Vvamp it can be slow or instant doesn’t matter

Comment: @Jay then, in your loops change the step size of '10' to '1'. That way you'll check all pixels from 0,0 to 100,100. Keep in mind this only works for a 100x100 area

Comment: are you on windows? If so, does it only have to work on windows or cross-platform?

Comment: @Vvamp i’m windows. windows only is fine

Comment: @Jay I posted code that works for me. Let me know if it works and fulfills your requirements

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your code such that when you reach the color you want, it saves the position at a tuple of (x,y) coordinated. You will then be able to use such coordinated for later processing.

```
import ImageGrab
import win32api, win32con

color_I_want = #hex number describing the color
color_locations = []

px = ImageGrab.grab().load()
for y in range(0, 100):
    for x in range(0, 100):
        if px[x,y]==color_I_want:
            color_locations.append( (x,y) )

# Assuming you have a way to translate between the image coordinates and your desktop windows:

screen_locations = image2screen(color_locations) 

# This code then goes to the mouse coordinates 
for positions in screen_locations :
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
```

Comment: Thank you. But would this not check throughout the entire screen

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me on Windows. Keep in mind this moves you to the first pixel found. It also checks your entire screen(s). I decided to put it in a function, so the code could terminate as soon as the desired color was found.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import win32api, ctypes

def moveToDesiredColor(desiredColor, width : int, height : int):
    px = ImageGrab.grab().load()

    # Loop over each pixel 
    for y in range(0, height):
        for x in range(0, width):
            # If colors match, move cursor
            if px[x, y] == desiredColor: 
                win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
                return
            
w = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0) # Get screen width with ctypes
h = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1) # Get screen height with ctypes
color = (255, 255, 255) # Desired color

moveToDesiredColor(color, w, h) # Call the function
```

Although you will need to install 'pypiwin32': `pip install pypiwin32`

Comment: Works great. Thank you, but what if i wanted to move “slowly” towards the x,y?

Comment: Then you could use `autopy` instead of win32api. Simply install it with `pip install autopy`, import it and replace the line `win32api.SetCursorPos` to `autopy.mouse.smooth_move(x,y)`. [Read here for more info](https://www.autopy.org/documentation/api-reference/mouse.html#autopy.mouse.smooth_move).